# Version Visual Studio Code 2.18 Debugger Error

Tags: json

My system automatically upgrades to version 2.18 of MS Visual Code Studio.  Now when I try and debug my code on Windows 10, I get an error message

> TIMEOUT WAITING FOR DEBUGGER CONNECTION  OPEN LAUNCH.JSON.

I reinstalled Visual Studio Code and even went to an earlier version with no success.